# Driving a car in the UK with an Australian driver's license

Tags: uk, driving, driving-licenses

Two questions:

1. Is it legal to drive a car in the UK (London) with an Australian driver's license if we are coming for a week's visit?
2. Is it possible (and easy enough) for one to drive in the UK after having 4 years of driving experience in Australia?

Cheers.

Comment: Imagine if you couldn't do this? The world would pretty much fall apart.

Comment: note that if you're a younger person, it may be simply tricky / more expensive to hire a car.  yes it's very easy to drive in the UK.  everything is English-speaking obviously, and you're on the same side of the road.

Comment: @Fattie: You seem to have forgotten to add a <scarcasm/> tag. I've diven in the antipodes, I've driven thousands of miles in several different american states, I've driven in France, Spain & (Jeebus help me) Italy, and - other than the hour I drove in circles after leaving L.A.X. trying to find the 101 north, it's all been relatively easy.
However, the 4 hours I drove my old aunts small car - with the sticky clutch and wonky drivers side mirror - across London on a dark and wet Friday evening is still spoken of in hushed tones by the unfortunate people who lived through it with me.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier (I think that might have been the car)

Comment: The car didn't help, but it could have been a brand new Audi or Mercedes, it would still have been a white knuckle ride!

Comment: The simple answer to the actual question here is that **no, you are too young to rent a car in the UK**.  https://www.budget.co.uk/faqHelp.html

Comment: I think this should be no problem because I actually rented a car in Leeds back in 2009 with a U.S. drivers license

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Yes](https://www.gov.uk/driving-nongb-licence/y/a-visitor-to-great-britain/any-other-country), You can drive legally.

Your Australian driving experience will certainly help since both drive on same side. Traffic congestion can be a problem depending upon where you are. So it’s not like a piece of cake. People don’t really recommend tourists drive cars in central London but we don’t really know where you plan to drive.

If its going to be London, I would also recommend avoiding a car. Its just too much cost and hassle for not too big of a benefit. TFL is great and you are never too far away from a Tube station or a bus stop.

In London 3 things are all you need. Oyster Card, City Mapper and some £s :P

Comment: I believe, being there for only 7-9 days, we will probably be in the most touristy bits only. Really can't think of visiting Scotland in this time period.

Comment: No need at all to rent a car if you're visiting London - take the tube (and possibly buses). As well, if you stay in a good location, much will be within walking distance. More remote parts of England, plus Wales and Scotland, invite the use of a car, but if you're spending less than a week in the UK, I'd stick to London and save the car expense.

Comment: @PHPDeveloper a bit off-topic but you said *touristy bits only* do you know that the Scottish tourist industry is one the best in the world? Scotland **is** part of *touristy bit*

Comment: @HankyPanky I am sorry I must have mentioned touristy bits of "LONDON" only. Sorry.

Comment: Yep then absolutely avoid renting a car. London's public transport system is Awesome! And the amount you will be paying for using TFL will be lesser than even the congestion charges you have to pay for your rented car. Let alone the rental and fuel costs

Comment: @HankyPanky Thank you so much for such a useful piece of advise. Really appreciate it mate.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: I disagree that people don't recommend tourists drive cars in the UK. It's not very difficult place to drive. I do agree there's no advantage to using a car if you are just visiting and staying in London.

Comment: You don't even need an Oyster card these days, just a contactless credit/debit card. In fact contactless is better because a) you don't have to buy the card, and have the faff of getting a refund by returning it at the end of your holiday and b) there's a weekly cap that applies to contactless but bizarrely not to Oyster.

Comment: Cars in London drive, on average, at a sedate 7.5 mph, and drivers there are by-and-large fairly used to the erratic driving of others, so driving in London's not really much of a problem. It's a breeze when compared with Mexico City, say. I do agree that unless you're planning to head off to Oxford, say, or further afield, then having a car in central London is more of a nuisance than a pleasure.

Comment: @Strawberry - See e.g. [this recent article from the Evening Standard](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/transport/fouryear-delay-in-weekly-price-cap-costing-oyster-users-millions-a3643731.html). Perhaps I should clarify that I'm talking about automatic capping on pay-as-you-go, rather than the option to buy a week long ticket on your Oyster (which I believe does exist).

Comment: @AndyT !!! Thanks for the heads-up. I genuinely didn't know that. Luckily? these days I always use a credit card.

Comment: @AndyT Weekly travelcards on oyster do exist and are the same price as the monday to sunday capping on contactless. There are pros and cons to both systems, the advantage of the monday to sunday capping is it's automatic. The disadvantage is it can only run from monday to sunday.